# Accessing a logger across multiple modules in Python logging

Tags: python

I have a little question regarding the python logging module.

I have a simple logger

Logger=basicConfig()

How do I access the same logger using getLogger()?

Or does getLogger() give me a logging object which I can access?

If so how do I access the same logger in another program?

Apologies if it is the wrong place to ask this.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `logging` (start [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html), and see additional resources top-right)? It covers this use case (logging across multiple modules) in quite a lot of detail...

Comment: Thank you exactly what I was looking for... I read every other doc but this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Python `logging.getLogger(name)` returns always the same logger object with that name within the process.

The Python best practice of using of loggers is that your each Python module defines it own logger at the beginning of the `.py` file.:

```
  import logging

  logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

  # Do something with the logger
  def foobar():
       logger.debug("In foobar")
```

This allows you to later turn on and off and adjust the levels of  individual loggers using Python's `logging` configuration. Generally, you do not want to share the logger across modules unless you have some very specific use case.