# Send email with Python logging

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I'd like to send an email everytime `Logger.fatal` or `Logger.warn` is invoked.

Perhaps a solution could be to extend it and override the methods. But when you import logging, the only way to get a `Logger` class is using `logging.getLogger()`.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly what you need, but maybe you can get an existing logger by its name, then add an SMTPHandler to it.

Comment: It would be best if you read the Python logging HowTo at https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html . If explain all the option on configuring and modifying the logger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a best solution to override logger methods.

Python logging configuration supports multiple loggers which then support multiple *handlers* (files, stdout, email). Handlers in turn have different *formatters* (string format how log entry is displayed), but it's offtopic for this question.

In fact Python supports email logging out of the box through [SMTPHandler](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.handlers.html#smtphandler).

Because you did not include details about your application and logger setup it is not possible to give answer specific to your question. But generally outline is this

- Add a `SMTPHandler` handler root logger (call `logging.getLogger()` with arguments should give you the root lgoger)
- Make the handler level `WARN` so that it ignores `INFO`, and `DEBUG` levels

[See also proper mechanism to initialize loggers in your Python code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30533071/315168).

Comment: Good job on your gist mate :) works perfectly on python 3.0 even with modifications on our side.

Answer (score 0):

I have also created an [EmailHandler](https://red-mail.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extensions/logging.html#emailhandler) to [Red Mail](https://github.com/Miksus/red-mail) to make things easy for people.

It works like this:

```
import logging
from redmail import EmailHandler

# Create the email handler
hdlr = EmailHandler(
    host="localhost",
    port=0,
    username="me@example.com",
    password="<PASSWORD>",

    subject="Log Record: {record.levelname}",
    receivers=["me@example.com"],
    text="""
        Logging level: {{ record.levelname }}
        Message: {{ msg }}
    """,
    html="""
        <ul>
            <li>Logging level: {{ record.levelname }}</li>
            <li>Message: {{ msg }}</li>
        </ul>
    """,
)

# Add the handler
logger = logging.getLogger("mylogger")
logger.addHandler(hdlr)
```

It uses Jinja for templating for the bodies (that's why we used but regular string formatting for the subject. You can also use only `text` or just the `subject` if you wish to have simpler emails.

Then to use this, just log away:

```
logger.warning("Watch out!")
```

There is also a [MultiEmailHandler](https://red-mail.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extensions/logging.html#multiemailhandler) that sends multiple log records at once if you wish to avoid flooding your inbox with log messages.

##### Install

It's on PyPI so you can install it with:

```
pip install redmail
```

##### Relevant links:

- Source code: https://github.com/Miksus/red-mail
- Documentation: https://red-mail.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html
- Releases: https://pypi.org/project/redmail/